# Python - Loading data frame with multiple headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set which has voltages and current outputs of different rectifiers. These values are measured usually every two months and so they have a date that corresponds to them. Currently what I did was made a separate dataframe for each rectifier and made a dictionary of dataframes. After that I am stuck on how to make it where I can plot the dates vs the voltage/amps. Is there an easier way to do this that I might be missing? Below is a sample of the data as well as my code.

```
             1/1/2015           2/1/2015     3/1/2015   
Rectifier   Volts   Amps      Volts Amps    Volts   Amps
9E220ECP5001    11.10   31.95           11.30   31.05
9E220ECP5002    19.30   62.60           13.10   39.60
9E220ECP5003    4.50    6.30            4.60    6.30
9E220ECP5004    4.40    8.40            4.60    8.55
9E220ECP5005    20.90   41.40           17.60   32.07
9E220ECP5006    35.10   7.84            31.90   6.40
9E220ECP5007    13.50   22.72           17.30   29.12
9E220ECP5008    4.50    6.15            5.00    6.15


https://imgur.com/a/RJgtMWf

   
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("Rectifier_DB.xlsx", header = [0,1], index_col=0)


rectifiers = list(df.index.values)


rect_dict = {}
for index, rect in enumerate(rectifiers):
  rect_dict[rect] = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[index])
```

Comment: please post sample data directly into the question instead of providing an image.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to define the index column:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Rectifier_DB.xlsx', header=[0, 1], index_col=0)
```